# How to launch two Drools rules at same time?

Tags: drools, rules

I need to launch two different rules at same time. At this moment I have a drl file with these rules. The first rule has a timer, so it runs every minute

```
rule "periodicCheck"
    salience 20
    timer (cron:0 0/1 * * * ?)
    when   
        $crisis: CrisisContext()  
    then  
        Date date = new Date();       
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~Check File~~~~~~~~~~~~"+date);  
end
```

The other rule is doing some calculations that might take 4 minutes:

```
rule "Distance"
    when
        $event: Event(isNewEvent())
        $crisis: CrisisContext()
    then
        myApp.getDistance($crisisContext);
end
```

So, when this rule is running, I don't know if my first rule is also running.

Are there running in parallel?? Is it possible to run each rule in parallel??

Thank in advance!!

Jesús

Comment: First thing: drools does not support parallel execution of rules. If you want real parallel execution you will need to have 2 different ksessions in 2 different threads. Of course, synchronizing those ksessions is not an easy thing. May I ask why do you want to run them in parallel? Maybe there is some other way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot of, Estaban

Yes, I'm developing other solution, but I want to know if this solution is possible.

The only reason I want to run both rules at once is by checking a change while performing other tasks. But this I can do it straight with threads :)

Best regards, Jesús!!